# Heroku Postgres connections not utilized after upgrade

Tags: postgresql, heroku

We have suddenly started to receive lot of traffic, upgraded to standard tear and added 24 Dynos to support that.

We had to change the Postgres plan from Hobby-basic to Standard-0 as hobby basic has only 20 connections.

Before upgrading, the hobby basic was using it's all connections.

After upgrade Standard-0 is only using 2 connections out of 120.

Need help to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now. The fault was, after upgrading the database plan to Standard-0 database, DATABASE_URL was containing a different port.

Our application was searching for the default port.